# Why does Visual Studio 2022 take so long to publish with Blazor wasm?

Tags: blazor, webassembly

When updating visual studio to the latest version 17.4.3, when I make a publication with a Blazor application it takes half an hour to do it and it stays a long time in the following line:

```
--enable-serialization-discovery --skip-unresolved true  --notrimwarn --link-attributes "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks\build\6.0_suppressions.xml
```

I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it but it continued to publish for a long time, staying on the same line

Comment: VS 2022 doesn't take 30 minutes to publish. What you posted isn't a `dotnet publish` command or even part of one. What application are you building and where did this line come from? Googling for `--enable-serialization-discovery` returns a couple of Xamarin issues, nothing related to web applications

Comment: It is and I have the same issue. It's not dotnet publish, but publishing from inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, I've been having the same issue suddenly. Not sure if it started after I upgraded to 2022 or before... but it suddenly started happening. One thing to note is that a few times Sophos has had issues while publishing in my case. Not sure if it's related or a bad coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps involved in a blazor wasm publish that do not happen when you are just debugging or running Blazor WASM. Without out seeing your project file its hard to determine exactly why things are taking so long.

Here are a few steps are done in a publish which are expensive and can add significantly to the build time.

- IL Trimming - Publish will strip all unreferenced code from the assemblies to reduce the application size.
- Compression - The publish will compress all of the resources (dll's, static assets, etc) to ensure efficient transfer over the wire.
- Ahead of Time Compilation (AOT) - If this is enabled then the build times will be significantly higher as your trimmed assemblies will be compiled directly to wasm.

If you really want to determine which part of the build is taking the most time I would recommend generating a binlog of the publish and reviewing it to see which msbuild tasks are taking the longest. See [How to get MSBuild binlogs using command line](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018402099-How-to-get-MSBuild-binlogs-using-command-line). You can produce a binlog for your publish and analyze it using [MSBuild Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/). The log viewer should show all the msbuild tasks executed by the publish and their durations. This might help you identify what is taking the longest and it may potentially be a step you can disable. At a minimum it should at least give you a good idea on all the steps the publish is performing and which ones are contributing the most in the long build time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, but was able to trace down to a Nuget I use Syncfusion.Blazor.  Once I search for the problem on their help forms I found the following web site https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/178754/unable-to-publish-wasm-version-in-release
.  I removed Syncfusion.Blazor then added Syncfusion.Blazor.Cards, Syncfusion.Blazor.Core, Syncfusion.Blazor.Grid to cover **my needs**.  My publish time went from 46-95 minutes to 5-15 minutes on both my system and my Azure CI/CD pipeline.

Not to say you are using Syncfusion, but if you are check your Nugets.  Also if you are using other Nugets there might be a lot of striping.